# Why template tag does not render of the 'Bloqs' add-on on front pages?

Tags: add-on

I have uploaded some changes to my site and suddenly the pages of the site is broken due to the template tags of 'Bloqs' add-on are not working but there is no error or warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your new changes are related to adding the new fields to the channel then there will be a chance the title of the new fields are the same as the title of fields of the **Bloqs** add-on. Because we had faced